# In a ListView containing Buttons, how to get Index of the clicked one?

Tags: wpf, listview, button

I have a `ListView` containing only buttons. What I want to do is pretty simple, I want to have the index of the button that has been clicked. The count of the list varies from 0 to 100, so when the user clicks on button 6, I need this number for processing.

I defined my `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView Name="myListView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataModel}, 
          Path=StatusList, 
          Mode=OneWay}">
          <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemsPanel>

          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Mode=OneWay}"  
                            Click="Button_Click"/> 
                </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

My original idea was to create a custom button with an ID and bind the index to the ID but I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried:

```
int a = myListView.Items.IndexOf(((Button)sender));
```

inside the event handler, but it always returns 0xffffffff
can anybody tell me how to get the index of the clicked button?

Comment: why you need the index of the clicked button? hopefully you dont take the index to look for the dataitem??

Comment: I need the index of the button because I have to run a query to get the appropriate result of a device connected to the server, and that device has the same number as the buttons index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

Swap your ListView with an ItemsControl and set an AlternationCount to a very high number (higher than the max count elements in your list).
Make a command and pass the current index as a parameter.

**XAML:**

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
  <CommandBinding 
   Command="Select" 
   Executed="Click_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<ItemsControl AlternationCount="9999" Name="myListView" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataModel}, 
      Path=StatusList, 
      Mode=OneWay}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Command="Select"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Width="200" Height="20" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void Click_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Index: " + e.Parameter.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but when I add a line to change the background using a converter, the converter does not apply. I simply added the following line under the content binding (which I altered to a Tag binding) do you have any idea why?

Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataModel}, Path=StatusList, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}"

Comment: I fixed that myself Background="{Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}"

Comment: Glad I could help ... 
If you have problems with bindings in the future have a look in the output window. The errors should be listed there.

Answer (score 31):

Use the DataContext to find the item:

```
var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
int index = myListView.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it now returns 0x00000000 for every clicked item. Maybe because the content is never set?

Comment: This works with DataTemplates in lists such as your example, can you show me your code? Maybe the DataContext property of the button is set differently. If it returns 0 that means it thinks you clicked the first item.

Comment: well except for the sourrounding <Grid><DockPanel> there is no more code. I tried Button 4 and 10, nothing changed.

Comment: Great example Bas. I was trying to figure out how to click an image on a listviewitem and have the handler know which item it was, and this did the trick. Dim item As MyItem = CType(sender, FrameworkElement).DataContext ... thanks!!!!

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me =)

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    MyDataModelElementClass myDataModelElementClass = (MyDataModelElementClass)button.BindingContext;
    var index = myDataModel.IndexOf(myDataModelElementClass);
}
```